# Program configuration data in Unix/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, configuration-files

What is recommended way to keep a user configuration data in Unix/Linux?
My programming language is C++. Configuration data will be kept in XML/text/binary format, I have no problem with handling such files. I want to know where can I keep them. For example, in the Windows OS configuration data may be kept in the Registry (old way) or in user application data directory. What about Linux?
I need read/write access to configuration files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept of the registry is peculiar to Windows, and Microsoft once admitted to it being ill-conceived (see [this](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/why-the-windows-registry-sucks-technically/), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Disadvantages), [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20100412072811/http://www.insidetheregistry.com/regdatabase/browse.aspx?keyid=1030), [this (see #2)](http://www.pcworld.com/article/133191/article.html), and [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/was-the-windows-registry-a-good-idea/)).

In Unix and Linux, configuration for system-wide programs is in /etc or maybe an application-specific subdirectory.

Per user configuration data are kept in the user's home directory in a hidden file—in text format—or an application-specific hidden directory in the user's home directory.  The proper way to reference the home directory is through the environment variable `HOME`.  Hidden files and directories are created by making `.` the first character of the name.

Examples for system-wide configuration is `/etc/wgetrc` and `/etc/ssh/`.  Examples of per-user data are `$HOME/.bashrc` and `$HOME/.mozilla/`.

Comment: You should not rely on the environment variable HOME.  Since we're talking C++ which can make system calls, you should do `struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());` (or `getpwuid_r` if you need thread safety) and then use the value of `pw->pw_dir`

Comment: Good suggestion.  I've never had a problem using $HOME.  I notice many programs must work that way too, since sometimes I've overridden HOME with useful, expected results.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will follow this. BTW, can I use "~" for the home directory in the program?

Comment: Actually, I would go with `getenv("HOME")` and fall back on `getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir`, to allow a user to override the home directory if desired.  See the XDG basedir spec mentioned by ergosys: it allows for user overrides of just about everything.

Comment: @alex:  no, `~` is a magic shell symbol.  Only if the program uses the shell to expand file specifications would that work.  If there's a library function, I don't know about it.

Comment: @wallyk `man 3 wordexp` http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wordexp.html

Answer (score 4):

The XDG Base Directory Specification specifies where configuration and other files should be stored in Linux and other X-based operating systems:

http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/basedir-spec

This is the modern way, and may eventually reduce the dotfile mess in the typical user's home directory.

Answer (score 2):

Dotfiles are the classic Unix solution.  If you want to deal with reading/writing everything yourself, go for it.

However, most modern programs I use have used [GConf](http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/) for storing preferences.  It makes a lot of things easier, both as a developer and as a user (and apparently as an administrator, but I have no experience there).

Comment: Good point about GConf, thank you. In my case, I have cross-platform code for managing XML configuration files, which is already running in Windows. Having this already done, I need to add platform-specific code to select configuration files path.

Comment: http://api.kde.org/4.0-api/kdelibs-apidocs/kdecore/html/classKConfig.html for the *other* popular desktop's configuration scheme.

Answer (score 1):

That depends a little on your flavor of Linux but as a general rule most programs have the system default configuration somewhere in /etc with .config files in your home directory that can override the defaults in the /etc dir.

---

Great point .config should be .[Name of config file]

Comment: You might want to clarify that by ".config" you actually mean a file whose name starts with ".", *not* a file with a ".config" extension. The "." prefix is to keep the files "hidden" by default. Programs that have a bunch of config files will sometime have a ".config" directory, with the files in there. Also, old-skool Unix apps tend to use the name ".[appname]rc" for their config file/directory.